# how to make ASP.NET datagridview sort number correctly?

Tags: asp.net

I have bound a table to a gridview with autogenerated columns. First db column is numerical id. But viewgrid sorts the html column as if it was character type (1, 2, 213, 4,...).

How to make it take into account data type ?

Comment: One reason could be data type of ID filed in table varchar type not Integer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `DataFormatString` in html code of GridView

```
DataFormatString="{0:N}"
```

More about [BoundColumn.DataFormatString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundcolumn.dataformatstring.aspx)

> N = Displays numeric values in number format.